# Generate documentation doxygen style without commenting code

Tags: documentation, doxygen

I am looking for a way to create documentation pages in a similar style to Doxygen but I don't want to have to put the documentation into my code as comments. The optimal way would be to instead typing that into normal text files or something and then generate the pages from that.

From what I've understood, Doxygen doesn't support this so I am wondering if there are any alternatives out there that are able to do what i am looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternative ways for adding doxygen documentation to classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075653/alternative-ways-for-adding-doxygen-documentation-to-classes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create in your `*.dox` file in the section INPUT reference to folder where you place regular text files. For example:

```
INPUT = ./supplement
```

After that you can create regular text files just place `/*!` in the beginning and `*/` at the end. And classify it with `\page` or other tags for section. For example:

My.txt

```
/*!
  \page threading Describe Threading tech
  In details this describe cases:
  \li case 1
  \li case 2
*/
```

You can place multiple `\page` declarations in the single file (see http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdpage)

Comment: Didn't realise it could do that.
Cheers!